# EF Code First: How to search over multiple tables / entities?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I've got 4 unrelated entities and I would like to query them for a certain keyword. Each entity had a LastModified field and I would like to return the top 50 result of the search over the 4 tables order by the LastModified field. Is this even possible?

<sub>In the past I've used a view to do this kind of stuff... but I don't understand how to achieve it with **EF Code First**.</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to:

- Search each table
- Transform the results into a common type
- Merge the results
- Sort/select from this merged list
- Take the first 50 results.

The first two can be done with LINQ to Entities, the latter three with LINQ to Objects.

**EDIT** This approach would look something like:

```
var resA = from a in db.A
           where ConditionA(a)
           select MakeSharedFromA(a);
var resB = from b in db.B
           where ConditionB(b)
           select MakeSharedFromB(b);
var resC = from c in db.C
           where ConditionC(c)
           select MakeSharedFromC(c);
var resD = from d in db.D
           where ConditionD(d)
           select MakeSharedFromD(d);

var merged = resA.AsEnumerable().Take(50)
                 .Concat(resB.AsEnumerable().Take(50))
                 .Concat(resC.AsEnumerable().Take(50))
                 .Concat(resD.AsEnumerable().Take(50));

var res = merged.Sort(x => x.SortField).Take(50);
```

If each of the `MakeSharedFromX` methods can be replaced by a lambda (to give an expression tree) which is limited to operators and functions that LINQ to Entities supports, then drop the `AsEnumerable` and `Take` calls from the concatenation step and all can be carried out server side.

Comment: This will cause me to select at least 50 records from each table. Is there a way to put it all in LINQ to Entities (= LINQ to SQL)?

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker Only if the entity collections have the same type, otherwise you are trying to merge apples and oranges. Might be worth a try with the projection/transform step in L2E, and then see if L2E supports the [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351755.aspx) operator. I'll expand the A...

Comment: I've created for queries (in them an orderby and a Take(50)). Each query selects the record in a ResultRecord class. When I'm doing a `var searches = from s in setA.Concat(setB).Concat(setC).Concat(setD) orderby s.Modified select s;` everything works perfect! Don't know about performance implications.

Comment: I would probably go with your gut regarding a stored proc or a view.   This seems like an area where KISS would apply rather than trying to make EF do something its not as good at and most ORMs in general would have issues with what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is this solution still valid for EF 6 or is there any better way?

Comment: Isn't the sorting wrong if you sort after you page? You need to sort every entity first and then page them. We're running into this problem at the moment as our entities are also unrelated.

Comment: @StephanBisschop Note the `Take(50)` after the sort: even if the first query gets the first 50 results after the sort don't need more than 50 results from that query.

Comment: @Richard Yes but I was referring to the first Take(50) from the 4 entities. Your paging is incorrect if you do not sort (e.g. Date desc) each entity before you take 50.

Comment: @StephanBisschop I see what you mean. Feel free to correct. (Today I wouldn't do this in the same way in any case.)